# Accessing all system properties from a maven2 mojo

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin

I've written a maven mojo that makes use of all of the properties defined for the project using an injected MavenProject object like this:

```
project.getProperties()
```

I then realized that property values specified at the command line like `-Dfoo=bar` are not being reflected in my mojo, only the property's value as its defined in the pom like:

```
<foo>super</foo>
```

How can my mojo access the value of `foo` as it's defined from the command-line versus the pom? Any ideas on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The properties defined from the command line should be available through the [System.getProperties()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29) method.

Comment: Thanks Jörn, yep, I've decided to go this route. I figured the maven plugin api would give me overrides in a cleaner fashion, but the system approach will work just fine.